# Optimizing delete queries in MongoDB using the "justOne" keyword

Tags: mongodb

I was wondering if the justOne keyword helps the speed of a remove query even if you are querying by a unique field (i.e. there is only one instance of the document).

For instance using pymongo:

```
for id in list_of_ids:
   db.remove({"_id":id})
```

Does it still speed up the query if I use the justOne argument?

```
for id in list_of_ids:
   db.remove({"_id":id},justOne=True)
```

It wouldn't make sense, but I don't know if mongo is smart enough to know that this is the unique id so of course there will only be one.

J

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, this will not speed up the query. First of all, Mongo will retrieve all documents, that match your condition and then perform one delete. Since Mongo will retrieve just one document, so - no speedup there.